# Join of output from DF and LSBLK Linux commands via bash

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I need to merge two outputs in Linux.
This:

```
lsblk -n -b --output KNAME,NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT | grep -v "fd0" | grep -v "loop" | grep -v "sr0" | grep -v "hdc" | grep -v "cdrom"
```

In a result I have:

```
sda   sda                   53687091200
sda1  └─sda1                53684994048
dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 /
sdb   sdb                 2147483648000
sdb1  └─sdb1              2147482599424
dm-1    ├─hddVG-dockerLV   536866717696 /var/lib/docker
dm-2    └─hddVG-hddLV     1610612736000 /dockerhdd
sdc   sdc                  536870912000
sdc1  └─sdc1               536869863424
dm-0    └─ssdVG-ssdLV      536866717696 /dockerssd
```

And this:

```
df --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay} | sed -e /^Filesystem/d | awk '{print $6 " " $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5}'
```

In a result I have:

```
/ /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8110496 40591632 17%
/dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 214133656 274642488 44%
/dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 83278236 1385191240 6%
/var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 76046204 412729940 16%
```

So, I want to `Join` via these points `/`, `/var/lib/docker`, `/dockerhdd`, `/dockerssd`. 
Important! I want to check this in another place, where we will have another mount points. Also I have to save structure of first output without sorting.

In a result I have to receive something like this:

```
sda   sda                   53687091200
sda1  └─sda1                53684994048
dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 / /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8110496 40591632 17%
sdb   sdb                 2147483648000
sdb1  └─sdb1              2147482599424
dm-1    ├─hddVG-dockerLV   536866717696 /var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 76046204 412729940 16%
dm-2    └─hddVG-hddLV     1610612736000 /dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 83278236 1385191240 6%
sdc   sdc                  536870912000
sdc1  └─sdc1               536869863424
dm-0    └─ssdVG-ssdLV      536866717696 /dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 214133656 274642488 44%
```

Of course better to have one-liner, but if it is not possible, we can send output to separate files and `join` them. Could You please help me in this ?

Comment: No, `lsblk` does not have these options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
 awk '!/^\/&^fd0&^loop&^sr0&^hdc&^cdrom/ { print $0" "arr[$4] } /^Filesystem/ { mrk=1;next } mrk==1 && /^\// { arr[$1]=$0 }' <<< $(df --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay};lsblk -n -b --output KNAME,NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT)
```

Redirect the two commands back into awk, stripping out any grep and sed processing. We process the df command first and where we find a line beginning with "Filesystem" we set a marker (mrk) to 1 and move to the next line. We then create an array (arr) indexed with the mountpoint and containing the line returned from the df command. We move onto the lsblk command and search for the lines starting with the KNAMEs required. We print the line from the lsblk command and append the value in the arr array indexed by the mount point ($4)

Comment: Very good answer. Thanks for help, but it does not work correctly. I have mixed columns.

Comment: Will most probably be the formatting of the output from the lsblk command. Can you try with the --raw flag

Comment: Not correct with `--raw`. I have needed line under another line

Comment: Ok, I've amended the solution to take account of the output of the lsblk and df commands from your local system.

Comment: Hello, now I see two outputs, one, by one

Comment: This command returns eveerything in just 1 line of results. You need to add carriage returns after joining results dfrom lsblk and df for each partition.